# Curses Library Backspace Issue

Tags: c, curses

I'm attempting to implement deleting characters in a simple window that utilizes the Curses library.

Basically, the window gets created with the following code for the border:

```
box(local_win, 0 , 0); // Set the border of the window to the default border style.
```

and later on when I go on to process a backspace, I do it with the following code:

```
initscr();
cbreak();
keypad(window, TRUE);
int ch; // The character pressed by the user.

while((ch = wgetch(window)) != EOF)
{
   switch(ch)
   {
      case KEY_BACKSPACE: // Handle the backspace.
      {
         wdelch(window); // Delete the character at the position in the window.

         wrefresh(window);
         refresh();
      }
   }
}
```

Although it does delete characters, it ends up pulling the right-hand-side vertical bar with it from the border, therefore creating a hole in the border. Am I doing something wrong here or is this a case where I'll have to manually insert a space after every delete in order to keep the border in its initial spot.

Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to re-insert a space just before the vertical bar, or (I'm not sure if this is possible) setup a scrolling region that's less than the full width of the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to implement that now and post back with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to erase, rather than delete, a character.

Comment: Hmmmm that's actually a good idea, I'll look into that solution since I got sidetracked and never got around to trying the space insertion.

Comment: I just went to try this but it appears that curses (not using ncurses), or at least the implementation I have, does not include an erasewchar(WIN *w) function, which I need since this deletion is happening in a window. Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempt to repair a window, the usual practice in curses is to create sub-windows.  For instance one might create a window on which the `box` is drawn, and create a subwindow of *that* (and smaller than the box) where text is drawn and updated.

Here is a sample program (using [`derwin`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_window.3x.html)):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int ch;
    WINDOW *frame;
    WINDOW *display;
    int xf, yf;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    frame = newwin(LINES - 5, COLS - 10, 2, 2);
    box(frame, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(frame);

    getmaxyx(frame, yf, xf);
    display = derwin(frame, yf - 2, xf - 2, 1, 1);

    keypad(display, TRUE);

    while ((ch = wgetch(display)) != ERR) {
        switch (ch) {
        case '\b':
        case KEY_BACKSPACE:
            getyx(display, yf, xf);
            if (wmove(display, yf, xf - 1) != ERR) {
                wdelch(display);
            }
            break;
        default:
            waddch(display, (chtype) ch);
            break;
        }
    }
    endwin();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```